# Error saving matplotlib animation in Gif

Tags: python, matplotlib, gif, animated-gif

I have a problem saving a set of 2D arrays into a Gif. I searched similar titles, but didn't find same problem.

I have 600 files with data, which are 93*226 float arrays. I just need to plot them into a gif file.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
from  matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

# reading files
path = '/home/Anton/Heat'
files = os.listdir(path)
files.sort()
print('Number of files:', len(files))
arr = []

for i in range(len(files[0:150])):  # read files
    file = files[i]
    df = pd.read_csv(path + '/'+ file, sep = ' ', skiprows = 2, header = None) # skip 2 lines
    arr.append(df.values[:,1:]) # skip 1st col
arr = np.array(arr)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,25))
zmin, zmax = 50, 1150  # scale for Z values
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=zmin, vmax=zmax, clip=False)
im = plt.imshow(np.transpose(arr[0,:,:]), animated = True, cmap = plt.cm.gist_heat, norm=norm)
plt.grid(False)
nst = arr.shape[0] # number of frames in Gif == number of files read

def update(i):
    im.set_array(np.transpose(arr[i,:,:]))
    return im

# create and save animation
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=range(nst), interval=50, repeat = False)
anim.save('/home/Anton/Heat_1/Heating_1.gif', writer='imagemagick')
```

So if I set in the loop number of files to read = 50

```
for i in range(len(files[0:50]))
```

, it works normally . Or, alternatively if I read all 600 files but save them in small resolution

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
...
anim.save('/home/Anton/Heat_1/Heating_1.gif', dpi = 50, writer='imagemagick')
```

it also works.

**However** when I set files number larger than ~50 (e.g. 150 as it is shown above) and/or larger figsize, I get an error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-171-7897cf1b47b2> in <module>()
     91 anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=50, repeat = False)
---> 92 anim.save('/home/zizin/Heat_1/Heating_1.gif', writer='imagemagick')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py in save(self, filename, writer, fps, dpi, codec, bitrate, extra_args, metadata, extra_anim, savefig_kwargs)
   1258                         # TODO: See if turning off blit is really necessary
   1259                         anim._draw_next_frame(d, blit=False)
-> 1260                     writer.grab_frame(**savefig_kwargs)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     97                 value = type()
     98             try:
---> 99                 self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py in saving(self, fig, outfile, dpi, *args, **kwargs)
    235             yield self
    236         finally:
--> 237             self.finish()
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py in finish(self)
    367     def finish(self):
    368         '''Finish any processing for writing the movie.'''
--> 369         self.cleanup()
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py in cleanup(self)
    406     def cleanup(self):
    407         '''Clean-up and collect the process used to write the movie file.'''
--> 408         out, err = self._proc.communicate()
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py in communicate(self, input, timeout)
    841 
    842             try:
--> 843                 stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py in _communicate(self, input, endtime, orig_timeout)
   1503                     selector.register(self.stdin, selectors.EVENT_WRITE)
   1504                 if self.stdout:
-> 1505                     selector.register(self.stdout, selectors.EVENT_READ)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/selectors.py in register(self, fileobj, events, data)
    349 
    350         def register(self, fileobj, events, data=None):
--> 351             key = super().register(fileobj, events, data)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/selectors.py in register(self, fileobj, events, data)
    235             raise ValueError("Invalid events: {!r}".format(events))
    236 
--> 237         key = SelectorKey(fileobj, self._fileobj_lookup(fileobj), events, data)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/selectors.py in _fileobj_lookup(self, fileobj)
    222         """
    223         try:
--> 224             return _fileobj_to_fd(fileobj)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/selectors.py in _fileobj_to_fd(fileobj)
     37         except (AttributeError, TypeError, ValueError):
     38             raise ValueError("Invalid file object: "
---> 39                              "{!r}".format(fileobj)) from None
ValueError: Invalid file object: <_io.BufferedReader name=54>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Using your code and randomly generated data I've successfully generated gifs with 600 or 1000 frames. You should try to do the same (i.e. bypass the reading of pictures) and see if that solves the problem, and maybe see if you can pinpoint if there is a specific picture file that causes the error?

Comment: Can that be unsufficient process memory limited by Linux? (although I have 64 GB RAM, and i9 with 8 cores)

Comment: I don't know enough about the differences in systems to know, but I doubt it since you seem to have a high-end CPU and lots of RAM. Here is the code I used if you want to test it out https://clippr.co/H1c1sWSNX41589

Comment: I remember there being a similar (not the same) error in a previous version of matplotlib when saving many (>1000) frames via ffmpeg. Are you using matplotlib 2.2.2?

Comment: I have matplotlib.__version__ 2.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have removed writer='imagemagick'
from

```
anim.save('/home/Anton/Heat_1/Heating.gif', writer='imagemagick')
```

and now it works. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I am having the same problem but when I remove `imagemagick` the gif runs only once and is not looping.